# var = (shape) (tensor)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently trying to grasp Surag Nair's work regarding neural networks.

In (https://github.com/suragnair/alpha-zero-general/blob/master/othello/keras/OthelloNNet.py) There is this line of code:

```
self.input_boards = keras.Input(shape=(self.board_x, self.board_y))    # s: batch_size x board_x x board_y
x_image = keras.layers.Reshape((self.board.grid_shape, 1))(self.input_boards)  # ??
```

How is `x_image = (shape)(tensor)` a valid call?
Input returns a tensor, Reshape returns a shape.
From my understanding, a tensor is a potential high level matrix and an operation, which might be done later.
But if I want to call that later, the input shape had to be the argument for the tensor, not the other way around?

I tried testing it, and this is the result:

```
class Connect4NN():
    def __init__(self, board, args):
        self.board = board
        self.action_size = board.action_space 
        self.args = args

        #Neural Net
        self.input_boards = keras.Input(shape = (self.board.grid_shape) ) #shape: batch size x X x Y (batch size not needed here)

        #tf.Tensorobject represents a partially defined computation that will eventually produce a value.
        self.input_boards = keras.Input(shape=self.board.grid_shape)    # s: batch_size x board_x x board_y
        x_image = keras.layers.Reshape((self.board.grid_shape, 1))(self.input_boards)  # ?? 

        print("input_boards : {}".format(self.input_boards))
        print("x_image: {}".format(x_image))
        return
```

in console:

```
b = Connect4()

args = "bla"

nn = Connect4NN(b,args)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-20-7d7efde846db>", line 1, in <module>
    nn = Connect4NN(b,args)

  File "D:/Programming/code/conn4neuralnet.py", line 22, in __init__
    x_image = keras.layers.Reshape((self.board.grid_shape, 1))(self.input_boards)  # ??

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 457, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 401, in call
    return K.reshape(inputs, (K.shape(inputs)[0],) + self.target_shape)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 1969, in reshape
    return tf.reshape(x, shape)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 7178, in reshape
    "Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 529, in _apply_op_helper
    (input_name, err))

ValueError: Tried to convert 'shape' to a tensor and failed. Error: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 1 and 0
    From merging shape 1 with other shapes. for 'reshape_1/Reshape/packed' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [], [2], [].
```

Adding the relevant part of my Connect4 bitboard implementation:

```
class Connect4():


    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [0, 0]
        self.height = [0,7,14,21,28,35,42]
        self.nn_height = [0,6,12,18,24,30,36]
        self.counter = 0
        self.moves = []
        self.nn_board = np.zeros(shape = 42, dtype = int)
        self.grid_shape = (6,7)
        self.action_space = 7
```

Comment: What is the value of self.board.grid_shape?

Comment: returns a tuple of the form (6,7)

Comment: Then to produce (6,7,1) you should do self.board.grid_shape + (1,)

Comment: yes thank you! I just added an x and y component to the board directly, to make it more clear but this would have worked as well.
I am not that familiar with the python syntax yet, so all these things like adding tuples, trailing commas,   asteriks etc. are really tough :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misconception, `Reshape` is a layer that performs the reshaping operation, it does not "return a shape". It takes a symbolic input tensor and returns the reshaped tensor, given the shape in the constructor.

The problem in our code is that the shapes are not right, a shape is a tuple with integers, it seems your tuple contains another tuple inside, and that is not supported. This code works fine as an example:

```
x = Input((2,2))
>>> x
<tf.Tensor 'input_2:0' shape=(?, 2, 2) dtype=float32>

x = Reshape((2,2,1))(x)
>>> x
<tf.Tensor 'reshape_1/Reshape:0' shape=(?, 2, 2, 1) dtype=float32>
```